# Send data without sending file in Node JS

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I have created a Node JS app to send file along with data. It works fine when I upload a file. I want to make the uploading file an option.
When I send data without file I got

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined(reading'filename')

I am using multer to upload file. I can download the file using res.download().

How can I fix this issue so that I can send data without the file.

This is my code:

index.js

```
app.post('/update',upload.single('file'), async(req,res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    console.log(req.file)
    const a_seq_s = req.body.a_seq;
    const input_user_s = req.body.input_user;
    const input_email_s = req.body.input_email;
    const acpt_id_s = req.body.acpt_id;
    const acpt_memo_s = req.body.acpt_memo;
    const acpt_r_memo_s = req.body.acpt_r_memo;
    const file_server = req.file.filename || '';
    try{
        const query = await pool;
        const result = await query.request()
                            .input('A_SEQ',a_seq_s)
                            .input('INPUT_USER', input_user_s)
                            .input('INPUT_EMAIL',input_email_s)
                            .input('ACPT_ID',acpt_id_s)
                            .input('ACPT_MEMO',acpt_memo_s)
                            .input('ACPT_R_MEMO',acpt_r_memo_s)
                            .input('FILE_NAME',file_server || '')
                            .execute("USP_TS_M_S_Nodejs")
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(500);
        res.send(err.message);
    }
    res.send('<script>window.close()</script>')
})
```

update.ejs

```
<form id="update" name="update" action="/update" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table border="1">
        <input id="a_seq" name="a_seq" value="<%=result_data[id]['A_SEQ']%>" hidden>
        <tr >
            <th scope="row">Q_name</th>
            <td>
                <input id="input_user" name="input_user" class="input" value="<%=result_data[id]['INPUT_USER']%>" >
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Q_mail</th>
            <td>
                <input id="input_email" name="input_email" class="input" value="<%=result_data[id]['INPUT_EMAIL']%>" >
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">Q_ID</th>
            <td>
                <input id="acpt_id" name="acpt_id" class="input" value="<%=result_data[id]['ACPT_ID']%>">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 200px;">
            <th scope="row">ask_memo</th>
            <td>
                <textarea id="acpt_memo" name="acpt_memo" class="input" value="<%=result_data[id][''][0]%>" style="height: 200px;" size="100"><%=result_data[id][''][0]%></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 200px;">
            <th scope="row">memo</th>
            <td>
                <textarea id="acpt_r_memo" name="acpt_r_memo" class="input" value="<%=result_data[id][''][1]%>" style="height: 200px;" size="100"><%=result_data[id][''][1]%></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">file</th>
            <td>
                <input type="file" id="file" name="file" value="<%=result_data[id]['FILE_SERVER']%>" class="input"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
```

At first, I have tried to fix this issue in update.ejs file. But then I realized may be I have to fix this in index.js.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: A language barrier is making it difficult for me to understand the problem you're trying to describe.  But one thing is certain, this is wrong: `value="<%=result_data[id]['FILE_SERVER']%>"`  You can't pre-set the `value` of an `input type="file"`.  (Imagine for a moment a world in which any website could pre-populate a hidden file input with any path from your computer and trigger a form post to upload any file from your computer.)  The user has to choose the file, the browser won't allow you to choose it for them.

Comment: *If* the problem is that sometimes the user doesn't select a file and `req.file` is `null` (or `undefined`?) then you can use optional chaining: `const file_server = req.file?.filename || '';`  Or, more verbosely with the ternary conditional operator: `const file_server = req.file ? req.file.filename : '';`  Or any other approach you like which simply checks if `req.file` *exists* before using it.

Comment: @David thank you for your advise. `const file_server = req.file? req.file.filename: '';` this is what i want to solve problem! and sorry for my english skill :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the code assumes that `req.file` will always be defined. So if there is no file, `req.file.filename` will cause `TypeError`.

You can modify your code by checking if `req.file` exists or not. If exists you can read it's properties. Else you can set it as `''`.

```
app.post('/update', upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.file);

    // Check if req.file exists
    const file_server = req.file ? req.file.filename : '';

    const a_seq_s = req.body.a_seq;
    const input_user_s = req.body.input_user;
    const input_email_s = req.body.input_email;
    const acpt_id_s = req.body.acpt_id;
    const acpt_memo_s = req.body.acpt_memo;
    const acpt_r_memo_s = req.body.acpt_r_memo;

    try {
        const query = await pool;
        const result = await query.request()
            .input('A_SEQ', a_seq_s)
            .input('INPUT_USER', input_user_s)
            .input('INPUT_EMAIL', input_email_s)
            .input('ACPT_ID', acpt_id_s)
            .input('ACPT_MEMO', acpt_memo_s)
            .input('ACPT_R_MEMO', acpt_r_memo_s)
            .input('FILE_NAME', file_server)
            .execute("USP_TS_M_S_Nodejs");
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err.message);
    }

    res.send('<script>window.close()</script>');
});
```